# Get the public properties of a class without creating an instance of it?

Tags: javascript, reflection, typescript

Let's imagine that we have a JavaScript class:

```
var Person = (function () {
    function Person(name, surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    Person.prototype.saySomething = function (something) {
        return this.name + " " + this.surname + " says: " + something;
    };
    return Person;
})();
```

I want to iterate its methods and properties. I have no problem with the methods.

```
  var proto = Person.prototype,
      methods = Object.keys(proto);

  // iterate class methods ["saySomething"]
  for (var i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
    // do something...
  }
```

My problem comes when I want to iterate its properties:

```
  var proto = Person.prototype,
      targetInstance = new Person(), // this is my problem!
      properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(targetInstance),

  // iterate class properties ["name", "surname"]
  for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
    // do something...
  }
```

The only way that I have found is to **create an instance** and use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`. I want to use this code as part of a framework so I will not have control over the classes defined by other developers. I want to avoid the need of creating an instance because if the constructor had some sort of validation like:

```
function Person(name, surname) {

  if(typeof name === "undefined" || typeof surname === "undefined"){ 
    throw new Error() 
  }

  this.name = name;
  this.surname = surname;
}
```

I wouldn't be able to use the code above. Do you know if it is possible to get the public properties of a class without creating an instance of it?

Comment: "As far as I know, 'no.'"  You need to be able to interrogate "the Prototype," and offhand I don't know how you would do that . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you know if it is possible to get the public properties of a class without creating an instance of it?

If you are talking about *runtime* them no, not without ugly hacks like `toString` (which gives you a `string` representation of the function body).

However you can get these at compile time using the TypeScript language service and then do code generation to assist the runtime (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Language-Service-API).

Neither of these are trivial.

Comment: I was thinking about `toString()` but I wasn't aware of the language service API thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

The properties don't exist until an object constructs them.
If your class looked like:

```
var Person = (function () {
    Person.prototype.name = null;    
    Person.prototype.surname = null;
    function Person(name, surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    Person.prototype.saySomething = function (something) {
        return this.name + " " + this.surname + " says: " + something;
    };
    return Person;
})();
```

you would see name and surname too, but of course you can't count on the objects looking like that.