# Is there any way to reflect public instance class fields from the javascript class declaration?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next, class-fields

The ecmascript candidate spec allows to declare class fields like:

```js
class A {
    foo;
}
```

or with value assignment like:

```js
class A {
    foo = 'abc';
}
```

[Public instance fields spec on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields#Public_instance_fields)

Is there any way to reflect the list of declared fields names (and assigned value) from the class declaration in similar way how we are able to reflect class methods ? :

```js
class B {
    foo = 'abc';
    boo() {}
}
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(B.prototype) // => ["constructor", "boo"]
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've searched, you have to create an instance of the class itself to access the values of variables inside the scope.

So you can always list the default values of the constructor if you do the following:

```js
class B {
    foo = 'abc';
    boo() {}
}
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new B) // => ["foo"]
```

Hope that helps solving your question

Comment: I know that it is easy task with instance, but looking for solution without, directly from **declaration**.

Comment: Then no, the properties don't exist until an object constructs them.

You can see here for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518711/get-the-public-properties-of-a-class-without-creating-an-instance-of-it